# Including PHP functions from another folder

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, crud

My file structure is like this

> /project/a
>
> > a.php
>
> /project/b
>
> > b.php
>
> /project/c
>
> > Bootstrap Files
>
> /project/d
>
> > Javascript Files

And my `INDEX.PHP` which is contained in the `/project` root folder.
 
`a.php` contains the connection from PHP to my MSSQL database, `b.php` has a single `SELECT` database query (in a function).

When I do: `include(dirname(__FILE__)). '/project/b.php';` in my `INDEX.PHP` file throws this:
Warning: include_once(C:\wamp\www\project/b/b.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project\index.php .

How can I correctly manage php files then?

When I include the connection file (`a.php`) and do the query inside `INDEX.PHP` it works.

Comment: Try: DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of '/'. It's hard to tell what's going on but you're on windows so / is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: i am thinking the same, this looks wrong with some slash and back slash. `C:\wamp\www\project/b/b.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do
`include(dirname(__FILE__)). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'project'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'b.php';`

the most probable cause is that it messes because of windows directory separator that is a backslash

Comment: I'll try that, thank you! 
Also I did `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/b/b.php');` and worked too, so which way would do you recommend the most for a relatively big project?

Comment: Both are correct. It has nothing to do if the project is big. You can go with your way since it does not cause you any problems on windows. The `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant, is just a way to handle correctly the slashes and backslashes on both windows and unix systems